# Flask WTForms Security SQL Injection on Submit Button

Tags: security, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, zap

I am using Flask WTForms for my website and ZAP for a security scan. The ZAP scan was showing SQL injection flaws for most of the form fields. I removed most of those by adding validators for all of the strings which get entered into the form.

PROBLEM: The ZAP scan still shows a vulnerability for the 'Submit' button. I tried adding validators for the submit button but this returns the error:

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not bool

which makes sense since the button should be a bool not a string.

How is it possible that the attacker can attack the submit button with the string

`"Log In' OR '1'='1' --"`

as shown below in the ZAP report? How can I secure this form? Thanks.

#flask code

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
...'other fields'''
    submit = SubmitField('Log In')
```

#ZAP report
SQL injection
Parameter: submit
Attack: Log In' OR '1'='1' --

The page results were successfully manipulated using the boolean conditions [Log In' AND '1'='1' -- ] and [Log In' OR '1'='1' -- ]
Data was NOT returned for the original parameter.
The vulnerability was detected by successfully retrieving more data than originally returned, by manipulating the parameter

Comment: You'd have to submit a normal request and a manipulated request. As it states more data will be returned in the manipulated case. You can/may/will determine if that extra data matters or not.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Is there anything I can do about this to prevent this injection? I don't understand how they can manipulate a submit button or what kind of additional data is being returned. I'm a beginner in this subject and I am just looking to make sure my site is secure. Thank you.